# How to route traffic for a collaborative editing system in Node.js

Tags: routing, load-balancing, node.js

I have a Node.js application that uses sockets.io to allow multiple users to edit the same document at the same time (a little like Google Docs).

I want to scale this out horizontally, but I'm stuck trying to figure out **how to ensure all the users editing a specific document end up connected to the same Node.js instance.**

For example, assume there are 2 documents (`doc-A` and `doc-B`), and two servers (`server-1` and `server-2`). Someone connects and starts editing `doc-A` on `server-1`. Another user connects, also wanting to edit `doc-A`. They must be sent to `server-1` to ensure the document remains consistent. Finally, a third user connects wanting to edit `doc-B`. We could send them to either server as no one is editing that document at the moment.

I'm sure every collaborative editing experience must solve this problem, but I can't figure out how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you think they need to be connected to the same server?

Comment: I'd take an even stronger stance than @MichaelHampton ; _don't_ design the system to require the edits to be made on the same server.

Comment: The document editing keeps a websocket connection open between client and server. Pretty much every key press is sent up to the server to be applied to the document and broadcast to the other users. Operational Transforms are used to resolve conflicts when multiple people are submitting changes to the same part of the document. It needs to be on the same server so each event does not need to atomically load the document from a persistant store, modify it and write it back, which would be too slow for a real time editing environment.